# How to create sessions for a login page?

Tags: php, forms

With two input fields, one for taking user name for the password. The username and password are fetched form the database, if the username and password combination is found, the flag is set to one.

```
$match = 1;
if ($match) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/myProfile');
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/errorpage');
}
```

Still there is a problem with the page that any one can type out the url "www.example.com/myPforile" and access the content. How to prevent that creating session variable?

Comment: If it's not redirecting then that would suggest a `500 internal server error`, check your error log.

Comment: "but when I am writing the url in the browser I am able to access the page. What am i missing?" - try reading what you just wrote. How are we supposed to understand your problem?

Comment: Please provide greater detail for your question. It is very difficult to understand what problem you're having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest.

First make sure you include `session_start();` at the top of your page.

Your login page should look something like this for the PHP code.

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Login') {

$err = array();
// will hold our errors

if(!$_POST['email'] || !$_POST['password'])
     $err[] = 'All the fields must be filled in!';

if(!count($err)) {

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}' AND pass='".$hash."'"));

if($row['id'])
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

}

}
```

Then on any page you want to require a login put something that checks for the session id you created.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || empty($_SESSION['id'])) {

// redirect them to the login page, they have no session id set

}
```

This is a basic example of something along the lines that I do. Definitely expand upon it and tweak it to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample of the code that I use to see if the session is set:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
    header('Location: http://example.com/errorpage');
}else{
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/myProfile');
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you are not protecting your `myProfile` page.

What you need to do, is set a session variable upon successful login and check for that session variable at the top of `myProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that your still able to access that page without being logged in in which case you would need to do something similar to

```
$logged in = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
if($loggedin) {
   die('whatever not allowed here or something')
}
```

Comment: Where should I create this session variable?

Comment: As soon as the login is verified. then when the user logs out do a session_destroy();

Comment: @Dibya, you create a session variable because then you know for sure if that variable is set, then the user is logged in and should have access to the profile page.

For example, if you didn't do this, anyone who knew the profile page was located at, http://www.example.com/myProfile could view it without ever having to login.